# Both Label in Grid (same column, diff row) move when text changed. Why?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Video showing the simulator: https://youtu.be/3ajany0iaCw

The codes:

```
  <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Switch Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            IsToggled="{Binding SwitchToggled}"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           Text="{Binding SwitchToggled, 
                          Converter={StaticResource Key=boolToStrConv}}"/>
    <Switch Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            x:Name="switch2"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference switch2},
                          Path=IsToggled,
                          Converter={StaticResource Key=boolToStrConv}}"/>
  </Grid>
```

My expectation is that no matter how the Label's text length is changed, it would both be centered - considering that both of them has a HorizontalOptions Center.

Why did this happened and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the container that is grid is within and the fact that you are centering (floating) your grid within that container.

Assign a background color to your grid and a different one to its container and you will see that its size **depends** upon what it is contains since you are `*` (star) its size and the grid itself is "floating" in the center of its container, change the contents of the grid, the size of the grid changes:

[image]

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Gray">           
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Switch Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Red" x:Name="switch1" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Red" Text="False" x:Name="label1" />
    <Switch Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Green" x:Name="switch2" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Green" Text="False" x:Name="label2" />
</Grid>
```

Lock the grid to fill its parent's width (via `StartAndExpand` in my example) and changing your label's text content will not cause your toggle's start position to move...

[image]

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Gray">            
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Switch Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Red" x:Name="switch1" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Red" Text="False" x:Name="label1" />
    <Switch Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Green" x:Name="switch2" />
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Green" Text="False" x:Name="label2" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I know I could've just accept this answer as correct and be done with it. Just writing this to personally say thank you :)